# Print $ inside \tt

Tags: verbatim, typewriter

How do I print a `$` inside `\tt`?

I tried escaping with a backslash, but didn't work.

```
\tt{\$}
```

throws an error.

> ! Argument of \OT1\^ has an
>   extra }

**Update**

Sorry, the issue was not with `$`, but with `^` in the next line.

Used `\textasciitilde` and everything worked fine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). I assume that your userid is a Star Trek reference. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill I never knew there was atoztoa in Star Trek... please enlighten me

Comment: It thought that your userid was as reference to ["Mr Atoz"](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/atoz) from [All Our Yesterdays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Our_Yesterdays_%28Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series%29)

Comment: @PeterGrill nah... I am not a fan...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\tt` is a switch, not a commmand with argument. Also it is obsolete. Nevertheless it works fine, and your problem is somewhere else. Make a complete example instead of sending code snippets.

```
\documentclass{article}
%not necessary but better
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily \$
\tt \$ %obsolete command
\verb+$+
\texttt{\$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I would advise you to use `\texttt` instead of `\tt`. See [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc). `\texttt` is the LaTeX equivalent of the Plain TeX `\tt`. If in Plain TeX, you write `{\tt \$}` and it should work. You have to enclose `\tt` in braces `{}` to make the typewriter type effect local to the text inside braces. In LaTeX, you write `\texttt{\$}` instead.